# Activate JAXB module for Jackson for RestTemplate as well as Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, resttemplate, jackson-dataformat-xml

I want to use JAXB annotations instead of Jackson's annotations for XML serialization and deserialization.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.3 which uses Spring 5.1.5 and Jackson 2.9.8.

So I defined my customizer bean

```java
@Bean
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jacksonCustomizer() {
  return (mapperBuilder) -> mapperBuilder
                            .modulesToInstall(new JaxbAnnotationModule())
                            .defaultUseWrapper(false);
}
```

which works automatically in Spring MVC `@RestController`s.

However it does not apply to requests/responses made with a `RestTemplate`.

For the `RestTemplate` to work I had to define a special `MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter` bean.

```java
@Bean
public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
  Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {

  XmlMapper mapper = builder.createXmlMapper(true).build();
  return new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(mapper);
}
```

Then, when the `RestTemplate` is needed I build it myself:

```java
@Autowired
public AClient(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder, MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlHttpMessageConverter) {

  this.xmlRestTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
                         .messageConverters(xmlHttpMessageConverter)
                         .build();
}
```

My problems with this approach are:

1. I have to define and autowire a second bean, how can I avoid the duplication of configuration?
2. The template I build is only valid for XML. I tried `addMessageConverters` but it yields weird errors with content negotiation.
3. In integration tests this means I have to mock the builder to create the same template to bind the mock MVC server to. This can get messy as soon as other template configurations pop up.

What I wish for: A single bean that provides a customizer and applies to Spring's MVC endpoints as well as the RestTemplateBuilder (replacing the default XmlHttpMessageConverter).

Comment: Which version of `Spring` do you use?

Comment: Spring 5.1.5, Spring Boot 2.1.3, Jackson Dataformat XML 2.9.8, I will update the question.